# I love the sliding up homepage at http://nautil.us/. How is this done? What css is required to replicate it? The answer is NOT a parallax library,

Tags: javascript, css

There is only one answer answer to this question. The CSS snippet and the JavaScript required. It is not parallax scrolling.its a blind that goes up and down OVER the website which is behind.

Comment: It's not parallax scrolling poeple! The cream on the cake is people posting the answer  from on other sites I posted the question on, that I posted In the first place. Do people even think ? I'm flexiverse on metafilter.

Comment: The answer is https://github.com/Victa/curtain.js.  I just can't believe it. Are the stack overflow moderator idiots ? Why wasn't there anyone smart enough to answer it? Disappointed I this place

Answer (score 2):

It's called Parallax scrolling, there's tons of tutorials and info about it. Like [this](http://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/) one.

Comment: I think it's something a little different, but then again I'm not the most credible source out there.

Comment: @AsianSquirrel I included the wrong link. It's fixed.

Comment: Really @panpsychist. I spend my Friday night at my house answering random strangers questions and you give me that response? Here's some more opinions on that exact same site and how it uses parallax scrolling. http://ask.metafilter.com/256436/Sliding-Up-Down-home-page-window-CSS-like-website-http-nautilus

Comment: Actually, I think you're just trolling. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638345/sliding-up-down-home-page-window-css-like-website-http-nautil-us

Comment: Kudos to you, @TylerMcGinnis... I respect you :)

Comment: I can't believe you Tyler, that metafilter question is one I POSTED!!  I've not chosen an answer as people are confused and assuming it's parallax scrolling without actually looking at it properly. It's like a blind it goes up a down over the website which is BEHIND the blind. Look again. I thought people here might be smarter than over at meta filter.

Comment: Yeah, and the answer you got was the same. That's 3 different people on 3 different postings who have all said the same thing...

Comment: Also above link is useless as it does not work on the ipad, and I'm on the ipad. But the site I'm trying to replicate works perfectly on the ipad!  It's all about this effect works wonderfully on the ipad as well. The answer needs to work responsive on the ipad people.

Comment: So that proves it's correct? That proves that a lot of people are dumb and DON'T UNDERSTAND THE QUESTION.

Answer (score 1):

Okay well hate to be harsh but if you're  going to sharply reject the answers of people that are just trying to help you (eg by obnoxiously putting half of your "question" in the title), then here's my answer.

There's this magic button called F12. In Chrome, IE, and FireFox, it should bring up the developer tools. These browsers (yes, even IE) have a "view source" option, as well as some more interactive inspection features. Then, you can inspect the DOM yourself (and the CSS and JS too!) to your heart's desire. Don't feel like looking through a couple hundred lines of code? It's okay, most people don't either, so try to be a little more gentle and give a little less attitude when you ask them to pick out code excerpts for you.

Thank you!

Comment: +1. Completely agree.

Comment: I've done that, I can't figure it out. Hence the question. If you actually bothered to actually look at the site, you would see obviously it's not parallax scrolling, it's like a blind. You pull up and Down over the website.

Comment: @panpsychist I did look at the site, which is why I commented that I didn't think it was parallax scrolling on Tyler's answer. I would never, ever answer a question without looking at the links first;that would be bad SO etiquette. My guess is that it hooks into scrolling, checking to see if the sliding div/header/whatever still overlaps the site content, and if so translates the sliding div upwards. Something like that; I'm not really an expert (you seem to have turned away the real gurus with the time of voice used in your question/demand)

Comment: AsianSquirrel. You are one smart MF. You are the ONLY person on this planet from all the places I've posted this question that has responded in a proper logical manner whilst responding with proper answers. Every one else has posted bullshit nonsense, and the question is on hold by lots of idiot moderators who are wielding power BUT NOT ENGAGEING thier brain cells.